# Google play Billing Sdk

Tags: google-play, play-billing-library

I am currently experiencing an issue with the integration of the Google Play Billing SDK. My application has already integrated Google Play, but I have encountered a problem. When a user's Play Store account is not associated with any payment method, my application calls querySkuDetailsAsync, and the response code is "OK," but the SkuDetails list is empty. However, if a user's Play Store account is linked to a card, the SkuDetails list returns data normally. I am unsure why this situation is occurring.

Is it intended behavior of our SDK to return an empty SkuDetails list in this case? Is anyone can answer this question ?  too many thanks!